# SQL Server 2008 - Shredding XML to tables need to keep UNKNOWN DATE value as NULL

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008, import, null

I was wondering if someone could help

I've successfully been able to import an XML document to a table with an XML data type in SQL Server2008, how ever when I try and shred from that table to a staging table any DATE values without an entered date are inserted to the staging table as 1900-01-01.

Is there a cleaver way i'm missing to stop it doing this and simply insert NULL instead. I could use NULLIF on the staging table and replace 1900-01-01 with null but I’m reluctant to do this in case there are genuine 1900-01-01 values.

My code looks something like this

```
SELECT tab.col.value('LastDate[1]','DATE') LastARD'

FROM   import.XMLCompanyDetail

 CROSS APPLY
          xmldata.nodes('//VN/CompanyList/Row') AS tab(col)
```

Many thanks

Please see below the example XML i'm importing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<VN>
<CompanyList>
<Row num="1"><CoNum>7878</CoNum><CoName>ExampleName</CoName><DInc>1978-12-30</DInc><DDis></DDis></Row>
</CompanyList>
</VN>
```

The date DDIS should be NULL but rather when it imports to my staging table it inserts 1901-01-01 instead.

updated code to show what I mean

```
create table staging_table
(DInc DATE NULL, LastARD DATE NULL);

with XMLCompanyDetail as 
(
SELECT CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<VN>
<CompanyList>
<Row num="1"><CoNum>7878</CoNum><CoName>ExampleName</CoName><DInc>1978-12-30</DInc><DDis></DDis></Row> 
</CompanyList>
</VN>
' AS XML) AS xmldata
)

INSERT INTO Staging_Table
SELECT tab.col.value('DInc[1]','DATE') DInc,
tab.col.value('DDis[1]','DATE') LastARD
FROM XMLCompanyDetail
CROSS APPLY
xmldata.nodes('//VN/CompanyList/Row') AS tab(col)

SELECT * FROM Staging_table
drop table staging_table
```

Comment: Could you supply a cut down version of the XML as well?

Comment: HI Martin, I've added the example XML. Many thanks for taking the time to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Following Update to the question the following works but I'm not sure if there is a better way.

```
SELECT tab.col.value('DInc[1][. != '''']','DATE') DInc,
tab.col.value('DDis[1][. != '''']','DATE') LastARD
FROM XMLCompanyDetail
CROSS APPLY
xmldata.nodes('//VN/CompanyList/Row') AS tab(col)
```

Comment: Oh yeah...no, no triggers on staging table. So its obviously just me doing something wrong somewhere along the lines. But now with your code I can find what i'm doing differently and fix. Thanks for taking the time to try and reproduce. I'll have a look at my code and update my question when I track down the difference.

Comment: There is still a problem but its my fault for providing inconstant code for the examples. I've updated the example code and will continue to see if I can find a solution.

Comment: @FairFunk. I see what you mean with the updated code. Using `tab.col.value('DDis[1][. != '''']','DATE') LastARD` worked for me. Not sure if there is a better way though. Feel free to unaccept my answer to get more input!

Comment: Cheers Martin, I'll leave it unaccepted for day or two to see if I get any more input and then probably accept your solution as it seems to do the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: @FairFunk The only improvement would be to use `""` instead of `''''`.

Comment: Excellent, cheers Denis. I think I'll go with this solution. I do love StackOverFlow reckon it would have taken me weeks of searching otherwise. Cheers guys. FairFunk

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `datetime` instead:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = ''

select @xml.value('LastDate[1]','datetime')
```

Wait, this returns `null`. That means that upon insert to your staging table this `null` value gets overridden by the default setting in that staging table. So remove that if you don't want this behavior to occur.